# Do we want an Uber tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Going through the reviews, I found https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/57706, a tag wiki for a new tag, [uber](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uber).

Do we want this tag? Granted, http://www.uber.com is a web app, but isn't most activity on Uber done with their app?

Should we encourage questions about Uber, or do we risk being flooded by questions about the Uber app?

For reference this is the only question with the [uber](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uber) tag at present:

[How does linking Spotify to Uber effect the Uber experience?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79305/how-does-linking-spotify-to-uber-affect-the-uber-experience)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not. At least not now.

What could someone possibly ask about the Web app? As you say, most of the action is in their native smartphone apps.

With the tag I would expect to start seeing a ton of questions related to the service as a whole.

- Why was my driver late?
- Is there a way to identify an Uber car?
- Why didn't I receive a receipt?

And that question isn't about the Uber Web app, either.